# Launch nightwatch with Selenium Server Usage

Tags: nightwatch.js

I read this - http://nightwatchjs.org/getingstarted#chromedriver
server path in this case is .jar file.
Is it possible to run selenium server without jar file? For example, https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone?
How can i point to file of selenium server in json?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium-standalone doesn't run without JARs, it just manages them for you.  You can find them after installing, example:

```
% npm install --save-dev selenium-standalone
...
% node_modules/selenium-standalone/bin/selenium-standalone install --silent
% find node_modules -name '*.jar'
node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/3.0.1-server.jar
```